# Fill Listbox with Results of SQL Query

Tags: sql, vba, listbox, ms-access-2010, recordset

Alright, I might be way off if what I've tried, but here goes. I am trying to execute a SQL query to return some records and then populate a listbox. Essentially, I want every record to display in a separate line. I have this in a separate module referencing the main form. I have heard some things about filling a datatable with the SQL results and then linking the listbox to that as well, but I'm not 100% sure what to do there either. I've just been trying to manually update the listbox with each result, but it doesn't seem to like it. I am using a recordset instead of a datatable, but like I said, it's because I'm unsure of how to use a datatable (haven't done it before but I am willing to learn)

```
Public Sub addCases()
'Uses windows login credentials to determine and return CSP's Manager's Name

'C
Dim i As Integer
Dim intX As Integer


Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strManager As String
Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Commit Tracker.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
strSQL = "SELECT "
    strSQL = strSQL & "* "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM "
    strSQL = strSQL & "CommitTrk "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE "
    strSQL = strSQL & "EMP_ID = '" & Username() & "'"
Set r = c.Execute(strSQL)

If r.EOF = False Then
    intX = 0
    vararray = r.GetRows()
    For i = LBound(vararray) To UBound(vararray)
       With frmCommitViewer.lstCases
           .AddItem
           .List(intX, 0) = r.Index(i)
       End With
       intX = intX + 1
    Next i
End If
r.Close
c.Close
Set r = Nothing
Set c = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: *it doesn't seem to like it* << Care to clarify what this means?  Do you get an error message? If so, what is the error message and which line does it break?  If not, please further explain how the achieved results differ from the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of the stupid array conversion, I'm still using the recordset directly.

```
If r.EOF = False Then
    With frmCommitViewer.lstCases
        .Clear
        Do
            .AddItem r![CASE_ID_NBR]
            r.MoveNext
        Loop Until r.EOF
    End With
End If
```

Super simple. Thanks to http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut10pfv.htm.

Comment: Don't use AddItem, it's really slow, you can dump all the records in one pass with `frmCommitViewer.lstCases.Columns = r.GetRows()`